# Get Document text at a certain position

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to check if the character before and after the % character is a space.  How can I do it using a Text object?

I have the paragraph x%y but I want it to be x % y.

```
function checkText() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let paragraph = body.getParagraphs();
    let text = paragraph[0].editAsText();
    console.log(text.getText());
    let range = text.findText("%");
    console.log(range.getStartOffset());
    // now I want to check if the character before and after the % is a blank
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
10:54:06 AM Notice  Execution started
10:54:07 AM Info    x%y
10:54:07 AM Info    1
10:54:06 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit of kluge but it does provide some information about where the ones that are missing spaces are.

```
function checkText() {
  let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let body = doc.getBody();
  let paragraph = body.getParagraphs();
  let text = paragraph[0].editAsText();
  let txt = text.getText();
  console.log(txt);
  let offset = null;
  try {
    do {
      let re2 = text.findText(" % ", offset);
      let so2 = re2.getStartOffset();
      let eo2 = re2.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      let re1 = text.findText("%", offset);
      let so1 = re1.getStartOffset();
      let eo1 = re1.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      if (so1 > so2 && eo1 < eo2) {
        console.log(`has both at paragraph ${0} offset ${so2 + 1}`)
        offset = re2
      } else {
        console.log(`there's one missing a space at paragraph ${0} offset ${eo1}`);
        offset = re1;
      }
    }
    while (offset.getEndOffsetInclusive() < txt.length)
  }
  catch (e) { }
  let end = "is near";
}
```

Comment: I want to use a Text object  like `.editAsText()`

Answer (score 0):

Is the following modified script close to your expected result?

#### Modified script:

```js
function checkText() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let paragraph = body.getParagraphs();
    let text = paragraph[0].editAsText();
    const str = text.getText();
    console.log(str); // <--- x%y
    let f = text.findText("%");
    if (f) {
      const startOffset = f.getStartOffset();
      const before = str.slice(startOffset - 1, startOffset);
      const after = str.slice(startOffset + 1, startOffset + 2);
      console.log([before, after]);
      if (![before, after].every(e => e == " ")) {
        text.insertText(startOffset + 1, " ")
        text.insertText(startOffset, " ");
        console.log(text.getText()); // <--- x % y
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

or

```js
function checkText() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let paragraph = body.getParagraphs();
    let text = paragraph[0].editAsText();
    let f = text.findText("%");
    if (f) {
      const textObj = f.getElement().asText().editAsText();
      const str = textObj.getText();
      console.log(str); // <--- x%y
      const startOffset = f.getStartOffset();
      const before = str.slice(startOffset - 1, startOffset);
      const after = str.slice(startOffset + 1, startOffset + 2);
      console.log([before, after]);
      if (![before, after].every(e => e == " ")) {
        textObj.insertText(startOffset + 1, " ")
        textObj.insertText(startOffset, " ");
        console.log(textObj.getText()); // <--- x % y
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

- The above scripts obtain the same results.
- When the 1st paragraph is `x%y`, the space is inserted by checking the before and after the character `%`. By this, `x%y` is modified to `x % y`.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the 1st paragraph is `x%y`. Please be careful about this.
- As additional information, when you want to search all texts in the Google Document, the following modification might be able to be used.

  ```js
  function checkText2() {
    const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const searchText = "%";
    let f = body.findText(searchText);
    while (f) {
      const textObj = f.getElement().asText().editAsText();
      const str = textObj.getText();
      const startOffset = f.getStartOffset();
      const before = str.slice(startOffset - 1, startOffset);
      const after = str.slice(startOffset + 1, startOffset + 2);
      if (![before, after].every(e => e == " ")) {
        textObj.insertText(startOffset + 1, " ")
        textObj.insertText(startOffset, " ");
        console.log(textObj.getText());
      }
      f = body.findText(searchText, f);
    }
  }
  ```
- From your reply `It’s like you have to have a Text object and a mirror string object to do this.`, if you want to directly replace, how about the following modification?

  ```js
  function checkText() {
    try {
      let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
      let body = doc.getBody();
      let paragraph = body.getParagraphs();
      let text = paragraph[0].editAsText();
      const str = text.getText();
      console.log(str); // <--- x%y
      let f = text.findText("[^ ]%[^ ]");
      if (f) {
        text.replaceText("%", " % ");
        console.log(text.getText()); // <--- x % y
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: It’s like you have to have a Text object and a mirror string object to do this.

Comment: @TheWizEd 
Thank you for replying. About `It’s like you have to have a Text object and a mirror string object to do this`, from your question, I guessed that you might have wanted to see the character before and after "%". So, I proposed the above modification. If you want to directly modify, how about the added script?

Answer (score 0):

I quess I left out an important part of my question.  The character % can occur throughout the paragraph.  If `i` is the offset of the character %, I was hoping there was a method of Text like `.charAt(i-1)` to see if the character was blank.

Instead I decided to use the shotgun approach as shown below.  Replace all "%" with " % ".  Then replace all multiple spaces with a space.

But Cooper and Tanaike thanks for your suggestions.  Using your suggestions I have to keep track of the fact that the Text object keeps expanding with the addition of the space and it doesn't map exactly with the string anymore.

[image]

[image]

```
function insertText() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let paragraph = body.getParagraphs();
    let text = paragraph[0].editAsText();
    console.log(text.getText());
    text.replaceText("%"," % ");
    text.replaceText("\\s{2,}"," ");
    console.log(text.getText());
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```